# How to remove the edges of the textfield of material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to remove the edges of the textfield of material ui

```js
<TextField className="form-control" value={this.state.referenceNumberOut} required={true} onChanged={this.handleReferenceNumberOut} errorMessage={(this.state.referenceNumberOut.length === 0 && this.state.onSubmission === true) ? this.state.required : ""} placeholder="text"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

in react inline styles are objects not strings, so try something like

```
<TextField style={{border: 'none'}} ....
```

read more at https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp

Comment: no, it doesn't work

Comment: if it is material-ui you may need to use inputStyle to modify the style of the inputbox itself

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify your HTML code :-

```
<div className="TextField-without-border-radius">
  <TextField
    name="url"
    variant="outlined"
  />
</div>
```

Write cs to remove border

```
.TextField-without-border-radius fieldset {
  border: 0;
}
```

Solution taken from this link https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13570